# Fisher-Yates Shuffle Algorithm error

Tags: arrays, algorithm, actionscript-3, for-loop

so I'm currently making a quiz game with Actionscript 3.0, and I wanna shuffle the questions with this Fisher-Yates Shuffle Algorithm:

This is my code:

```
var questions:Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function ShuffleArray(input:Array)
{
    for (var i:int=input.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var randomIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        var itemAtIndex:int = input[randomIndex];
        input[randomIndex] = input[i];
        input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
}

function buttoncorrect(event:MouseEvent):void
{
ShuffleArray(questions);
trace (questions);
var quest:int = questions.splice(questions, 1)[0];
trace(quest);
}

btntry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttoncorrect);
```

And here is the trace result:

```
9,7,5,10,4,8,6,2,1,3
9
7,1,2,6,8,10,5,4,3
7
5,2,3,10,6,1,8,4
5
4,3,10,6,2,8,1
4
2,1,8,3,6,10
2
10,8,6,1,3
10
3,8,6,1
3
1,8,6
1
6,8
6
8
0
```

Why do I always get the "0" value at the end? I should've get the value of "8" right?
Does someone know what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: your fisher-yates seems correct. The '0' at the end seems to be what is printed when trying to print trace of an empty array

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't your array empty on your last iteration?

Comment: Looks like it's empty but I have no idea why is it empty :(

Comment: Because you are removing one element at a time and keep doing so after the array contains a single element?

Comment: How do I stop removing it when it contains a single element? Sorry, I'm new to this..

Comment: Why are you passing the array as the first parameter to splice()?

Comment: Because I wanna take one value from the array that has been shuffled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var quest:int = questions.splice(questions, 1)[0];
```

The first parameter to [splice()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice()) is supposed to be a start index. Since you want to remove the first element, it should be zero:

```
var quest:int = questions.splice(0, 1)[0];
```

The reason your code works for each case except the last one is because of the way automatic type conversion from Array to int works. ActionScript is automatically converting the array passed as the first parameter to a zero when it has more than one element, but converts it to the value of the only element in the array when it has a single element. So it is effectively:

```
var quest:int = questions.splice(0, 1)[0];
```

right up until the last call, when you pass in an array containing the single value 8. Then the last time it gets called, you are effectively doing this:

```
var quest:int = questions.splice(8, 1)[0];
```

Since that index is beyond the end of the array, an empty array is returned and traces out as 0.